# No parameterless constructor defined when POST request in JSON Content Type with ASMX Web Service

Tags: c#, json, web-services, asmx

As title,

When I use fiddler to test the page -

http://localhost:59583/JSONtest.asmx/Test
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

and my request body is

```
{"header":{"sig":"abcdefg","timestamp":"2016-03-25T04:25:09.8395853Z"}}
```

It will response back to this error message:
**No parameterless constructor defined for type of \u0027System.String\u0027**

But if I put the JSON format with backslashes:

```
{"header":"{\"sig\":\"abcdefg\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-03-25T04:25:09.8395853Z\"}"}
```

The response will show the result I want which is correct.

How do I insert without backslashes JSON format?

This is my asmx code.

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string Test(string header)
    {
        return header;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `"header"` in your first snippet is a class with properties, not a single `string` as in your code. The error message is just confusing in my opinion.

The second snippet does have just one `string` as value for `"header"`, so that would be fine. If you really want `"header"` to be an object, you have to make a separate class for it in order to get it serialized right.

Comment: can you give me an example? not very understand

Comment: Your first `header` isn't a string, so you can't serialize it as such. The other one is since it is properly escaped.

Comment: Let's say i need to insert 2 parameters with many array value inside: 
`string header` and `string body`

then i have to insert the value for header `{"sig":"eeewrewre","timestamp":"2014-01-01T10:11:12Z"}`

and for body
`{"payerbanknum":"34434","payerbankname":"testbank"`}

How to type the request body in fiddler?

Comment: Then create a dictionary.

Comment: you mean i have to do something like this? [link](http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.com/2009/03/jquery-json-and-asmx-20-services.html)

Comment: Yes, a custom object indeed.

Comment: ok for the custom object, I got done that and I just not show it out. What I need now is how to pass this kind of request body without backslashes in with fiddler?

Comment: If you omit those slashes, it is an object and that is okay if your service can accept one. If you want a string, you need those slashes.

Comment: Ok understand, which mean I have to change all my variable to object type.

Comment: Yes, if that is what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

before sending the Ajax post request You can wrap both header object and it's value inside JSON.stringify()

```
var myHeader = {"header":JSON.stringify(headerValue)};
var myParams = JSON.stringify(myHeader);
```

then you can send the *myParams* variable as the data parameter into the ajax request

```
$.ajax('url',data:myParams  .....
```